# How to sync auto-scroll recyclerView with audio

Tags: android, audio, android-recyclerview, autoscroll

I have a recyclerView and audio.
I want recyclerView to auto-scroll according to audio.
I search in google and StackOverflow but didn't get a good result.
I want an app similar this:
[image]

Comment: post some of the code that you call "not a good result"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unforchunetly, I wrote the only recycler view and I have audio, I can't sync them same the embedded video together